# if (data[i,1] == 1): IndexError: index 869 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 869

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have the following code:

```
def findingGroups(data,i=0):
findingGroupsMatrix1=np.zeros(1)
findingGroupsMatrix2=np.zeros(1)
findingGroupsMatrix3=np.zeros(1)
findingGroupsMatrix4=np.zeros(1)
z=np.zeros(1)
print ("i",i)
while True:

    if (data[i,1] == 1):
        z[0]=i
        findingGroupsMatrix1=np.append(findingGroupsMatrix1,z,axis=0)

    elif data[i,1] == 2:
        z[0]=i
        findingGroupsMatrix2=np.append(findingGroupsMatrix2,z,axis=0)

    elif data[i,1] == 3:
        z[0]=i
        findingGroupsMatrix3=np.append(findingGroupsMatrix3,z,axis=0)

    elif data[i,1] == 4:
        z[0]=i
        findingGroupsMatrix4=np.append(findingGroupsMatrix4,z,axis=0)
    elif i == len(data):
        break
    i=i+1
```

And this is the error:  `if (data[i,1] == 1):
IndexError: index 869 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 869`

an data is a numpy.ndarray and shape (869, 10) . could u please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: If the size if 869, that means that index 868 is the last accessible index because arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: Sterling answer from @SterlingArcher

Comment: Your break test should come first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape is (869, 10), then the first subscripts run from 0-868.  Your loop control is faulty.  Since you know how many times you're going through the loop, use a "for".  The loop you have checks after it's too late.

```
for i in len(data):
    ....
```

You don't have to increment i any more.

Also, note that you only checked the index if the second element is not in the range 1-4.  This could also cause your loop to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If the shape of the array is `(869, 10)`, then the largest index in the object is at `(868, 9)` (since indexing starts at 0 as is typical with python sequences).

Answer (score 0):

python zero indexes. this means that the "first" element of an 869 element array is at 0, and the last is at 868. hence, referencing 869 will fail. use the search feature next time; this question could have been fixed by simply looking at python documentation, or previous questions, rather than posting on stack.

Comment: I'm sorry, Java..?! I mean you're not wrong, but wrong language.

Comment: The program is in Python -- which also uses 0-based indexing.  Tea break?

Comment: hadn't even read the question once i saw the error tbh because it was so generic. assumed java